# Does VAR use the first of last value of a vector?

Tags: r, var

I am using VARS package in order to forcast variables. I would like to know if I set a lag of 10, will VAR read the first or the last 10th values of my vector in order to forecast next variables (n.ahead)?

I have a 3852x24 matrix (daily values):

```
vardata<-VAR(Daily.Final[,2:24], p = 30, type = c("const"), season = NULL, exogen = NULL, lag.max = NULL)
```

Then I use predict():

```
predict(vardata, n.ahead = 7, ci = 0.95, dumvar = NULL)
```

Am I doing something wrong?

According to [this message](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/46742), AIC and SIC are fine for accessing the quality of the forecast, is there any other/extra coefficient or method to be sure that forecast values are relevant?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome NewJ. When you say "Am I doing something wrong?" are you asking for a general check?

Comment: Hello, I am talking about the methodology to forecast and about the general check. Thanks.

Comment: I want to know if VAR is using the first of last 10th value, if the method to forecast is right and if there is a better/extra way to access the quality of my forecast.
Thanks.